# Exibir numero de comentarios da tabela de um unico usuario

Tags: php

Como contar as linhas de comentários na tabela de comentários que foram adicionados por um determinado  usuário.

a tabela é essa

> ```
> id |post_body | posted_by | posted_to | date_added |removed   | post_id
> 1  |teste 1   |  joao     | maria     | 10-10-10   | no     | 23
> 2  |teste 2   |  carlos   | joao      | 10-10-10   | no     | 24
> 3  |teste 3   |  joao     | carlos    | 11-10-10   | no     | 25
> 4  |teste 4   |  joao     | maria     | 12-10-10   | no     | 26
> 4  |teste 4   |  maria    | joao      | 12-10-10   | no     | 27
> ```

quero exibir o numero de comentario só de joão.
ex: **total comentarios** 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select COUNT(ID) from usuario WHERE posted_by = 'joao'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o seguinte:

```
<?php 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tabela_comentarios WHERE posted_by = 'joao';");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo "Joao comentou: ".$row['total']." vezes!";
?>
```

OBS: Eu não testei o código. Mas acredito que funcione. Abraços!

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado !